I have two monitors connected to my computer, the computer only boots if one of them is disconnected. how can I fix it?
I have two monitors. The main monitor that I want it to boot to is AOC and the side monitor is Samsung. When I turn on my computer I get a black screen on both monitors. I can get around this by unplugging the Samsung monitor before I boot the computer. Is there a setting in the bios that I need to change? I am using the onboard graphics card on my ASRock Z170 Extreme4 mother board, and I'm running an Intel I7 if that matters. How can i fix this?
